# Link an access field in a table to excel cell

Tags: ms-access-2010

How can I link access field in a table to excel cell?
For example: I have an [Initial Balance] field in [Mortgage Cost] table, and I want to link to the cell which represent Initial Balance in Excel, how can I do that?
Thanks in adavance

Comment: Have you linked the Excel sheet?

Comment: In that case, DLookUp the Excel sheet as a table.

Comment: Can you be more specified?

Comment: It is best that you improve your question before people start complaining, see http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/dlookup-function-HA001228825.aspx and add some code with notes on where you are stuck.